# Code runs on OSX, Segmentation fault in Codeblocks VMbox

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

So when I run this in OSX it works correctly, but my class requires for it to work in a Xubuntu VMbox using Codeblocks. When I try to run it in Codeblocks or terminal of VMbox I get the error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'. Does this maybe have something to do with needing to import different libraries? I think I had that problem before.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
string filetoopen;
ifstream sudokutxtfile;
string txtline;
string sudokubox[9];
bool goodsudoku = true;
int i, j, row, column;

// Terminal input or default
if (argc == 2)
    filetoopen = argv[1];
else
    filetoopen = "sudokuboard.txt";
// Read in file, save to array, close file
sudokutxtfile.open(filetoopen);
while (getline(sudokutxtfile,txtline))
{
    sudokubox[row] = txtline;
    row++;
}
sudokutxtfile.close();
// Valid solution check
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++)
    {
        // check whether sudokubox[i][j] is valid at the i's row
        for (column = 0; column < 9; column++)
            if (column != j && sudokubox[i][column] == sudokubox[i][j])
                goodsudoku = false;

        // check whether sudokubox[i][j] is valid at the j's column
        for (row = 0; row < 9; row++)
            if (row != i && sudokubox[row][j] == sudokubox[i][j])
                goodsudoku = false;

        // check whether sudokubox[i][j] is valid in the 3-by-3 box
        for (row = (i / 3) * 3; row < (i / 3) * 3 + 3; row++)
            for (column = (j / 3) * 3; column < (j / 3) * 3 + 3; column++)
                if (row != i && column != j && sudokubox[row][column] == sudokubox[i][j])
                    goodsudoku = false;
    }
}
// Output 
if (goodsudoku == true)
    cout << "valid" << endl;
else
    cout << "invalid" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you run it with `gdb` or `valgrind` and tell us *where* the segmentation fault occurs? StackOverflow is not a debugger.

Comment: I'm new to c++, I don't know what either of those are

Comment: Make your class easier on you - read up on gdb and try using it on one of your programs.  Every class project will become **far** easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare these variables

```
int i, j, row, column
```

Then you do an assignment here

```
while (getline(sudokutxtfile,txtline))
{
    sudokubox[row] = txtline;
    row++;
}
```

`row` was never initialized, so whatever index you are trying to write to `sudokubox[row]` is probably out of range (or negative, or the color green, or who knows what)

Comment: Welcome to undefined behavior. 99% of the time, if the same code has different behavior on each compiler you use, you likely have undefined behavior somewhere.